# How to link an MDM Server in Apple Bussiness Manager

Tags: mdm, apple-business-manager, mobiledevice.framework

We are creating our own server for MDM, we followed apple suggested approach with following link (https://it-training.apple.com/tutorials/deployment/dm055)). After uploading public key (.pem file)  in ABM portal, new server token is generating and we downloaded the server token. But my question is where we need keep that server token(.P7M) in our servers...is there any specific path we have...if we gone through apple documents they are suggesting upload the server token to your MDM solution. The server token is a P7M file that your MDM server uses to securely connect to Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager. To learn how to upload the server token to your MDM solution, consult your MDM vendor’s documentation. But in my case we did't take any third party server's...so we don't have any vendor document.

Can you please help me to achieve this scenario.